# Outlook Addin-Office MarketPlace : Update not delivered to clients

Tags: deployment, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, marketplace

I've updated an outlook addin with a new version of th manifest file on the microsoft partner center.

It has be deployed on marketplace and appsource with the version updated.

But the update is not delivered to the clients computer on oulook and owa.

Does someone have encounterd the same issue?

How much time does it take to update on clients computer?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 24 hours to roll out the new add-in / manifest file. Here is what MS states for that in MSDN:

> It can take up to 24 hours for a new add-in deployment to show up for all users. It can take up to 72 hours for add-in updates, changes from turn on or turn off to reflect for users.

See [How long does it take for add-ins to show up for all users?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/centralized-deployment-faq?view=o365-worldwide#how-long-does-it-take-for-add-ins-to-show-up-for-all-users-) for more information.